# Replace built-in method of class instance. Python3.8. Pyside2

Tags: python-3.x, pyside2

I want to replace the built-in method `closeEvent` of `QMainWindow` class instance that handles the form close event.

CODE #1

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui_file_name = "ui\Main.ui"
ui_file = QFile(ui_file_name)
if not ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
    print("Cannot open {}: {}".format(ui_file_name, ui_file.errorString()))
    sys.exit(-1)
loader = QUiLoader()
window = loader.load(ui_file)
ui_file.close()
if not window:
    print(loader.errorString())
    sys.exit(-1)

def MainFormCloseEvent(event):
    print(event)
    event.ignore()

print(window.closeEvent)
window.closeEvent=MainFormCloseEvent
print(window.closeEvent)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code does not cause the `MainFormCloseEvent` function to be called when the form closes.
This code print the following information:
<**built-in** method closeEvent of PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow object at 0x000000000573BF80>
<function MainFormCloseEvent at 0x0000000002C37430>

But this code works well

CODE #2

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

def MainFormCloseEvent(event):
    print(event)
    event.ignore()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('Original class method')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
print(window.closeEvent)
window.closeEvent=MainFormCloseEvent
print(window.closeEvent)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code print the following information:
<**bound** method MainWindow.closeEvent of <**main**.MainWindow(0x51522b0) at 0x0000000004E8AF40>>
<function MainFormCloseEvent at 0x0000000002C37430>
<PySide2.QtGui.QCloseEvent object at 0x0000000004E8F340>

I can't understand the fundamental difference between these codes. I replace the class instance method in the same way, but in the first case it does not work, but in the second it works.
I only noticed the difference that in the first code, the `closeEvent` method is built-in and in the second code, the `closeEvent` method is bound. But I did not find in Google what it means and how to make the first code work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not replacing the method in the same way.

While creating a method as class attribute and overwriting an instance method at runtime *usually* has similar results, at the lower level it's not the same, which is extremely important when using complex modules like python binding to libraries written in other languages.

In general, attribute overwriting for methods should be done with extreme care only when it's safe to do it (and you *do* know what you're doing). It's also important to note that doing it for event handlers is risky, it makes debugging confusing and it also makes calling the default implementation more complex and awkward (you cannot call `super()`).

Unfortunately, PySide doesn't directly supports setting the UI on an existing widget instance, which is what you would do with PyQt and using a proper class, like in your second example), but there is a possible workaround, as explained in [this related post](//stackoverflow.com/q/27603350).

```py
class UiLoader(QtUiTools.QUiLoader):
    _baseinstance = None

    def createWidget(self, classname, parent=None, name=''):
        if parent is None and self._baseinstance is not None:
            widget = self._baseinstance
        else:
            widget = super().createWidget(classname, parent, name)
            if self._baseinstance is not None:
                setattr(self._baseinstance, name, widget)
        return widget

    def loadUi(self, uifile, baseinstance=None):
        self._baseinstance = baseinstance
        widget = self.load(uifile)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(baseinstance)
        return widget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ui_file_name = "ui\Main.ui"
        ui_file = QFile(ui_file_name)
        ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        loader = UiLoader()
        loader.loadUi(ui_file, self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('Original class method')
```

Still, you shouldn't overwrite the `closeEvent` with a basic function, instead you should probably opt for signals, further subclassing, or implement alternate ways to change the behavior (ie, using instance attributes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I understand that using QUiLoader is a more advanced way, meant for professionals. Since this is my first Python program, I decided to use the .ui to .py conversion. This method is well illustrated by numerous examples on the Internet. If I keep using QUiLoader I will get bogged down in questions.
In addition, I set up the conversion from .ui to .py directly from the QT Desiner menu (Form->View Python Code...->Save), so now this process does not cause much trouble.

Comment: P.S. to configure the conversion from .ui to .py from the QT Desiner menu, you need to do:
1). create "bin" folder in "C:\Python3810\Lib\site-packages\PySide2" folder
2). copy to the "C:\Python3810\Lib\site-packages\PySide2\bin" folder the "uic.exe" file , which is located in the "C:\Python3810\Lib\site-packages\PySide2" folder
3). run QT Designer "C:\Python3810\Lib\site-packages\PySide2\designer.exe"
Now QT Desiner's "Form" menu should contain "View Python Code..."

Comment: @Nikolas Being "professionals" or not doesn't really matter: StackOverflow is not intended for "pros" or "noobs", we just provide answers. There are several ways of using Designer created files, and none of them is wrong as long as it's done properly, with awareness and for good reasons. Coincidentally, there are also ways of doing it *really wrong* (with the common one being to edit uic generated files without knowing how they should be used, which is a recipe that 99% of the times gives awful results). There's nothing wrong in using the implementation above: on the contrary, it's quite fine.